# Getting first day of month without changing the Moment object

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to get the first day of a month, and then do other stuff with the Moment date object, but what happens is that when I do

```
moment().startOf('month').day()
```

It changes the day of the moment object to the first day of month, instead of simply reading it

```
var m = moment()
m.format('D') // 20
m.startOf('month').day()
m.format('D') // 1
```

Can I only read the first day, without changing the moment object?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I only read the first day, without changing the moment object?

I don't think you can, but you can clone it first. So assuming `m` is a Moment object you don't want to change:

```
    m.clone().startOf('month').day();
//   ^^^^^^^^
```

Example:

```js
var m = moment("2016-06-20", "YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(m.format("dddd Do"));                          // Monday 20th
console.log(m.clone().startOf('month').format("dddd Do")); // Wednesday 1st
// ----------^^^^^^^^
console.log(m.format("dddd Do"));                          // Monday 20th
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```